# Polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Okay, so I know there are a lot of polymorphism threads flying around but I have yet to encounter this situation.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void method1() {
        cout << "BaseMethod1" << endl;
    }

    void method2() {
        cout << "BaseMethod2" << endl;
    }
};

class Derive: public Base {
public:
    void method1() {
        cout << "DeriveMethod1" << endl;
        method2();
    }

    void method2() {
        cout << "DeriveMethod2" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* p = new Derive();
    p->method1();
}
```

What's tripping me up is method1 in the derived class calls a method2. So which method2 would it be since the method2 in the Base class wasn't declared as virtual?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: `method2()` parenthesis are missing if I am not wrong

Comment: @Pubby trying things won't necessarily lead to enlightenment in C++. In fact it can lead to a dangerous false sense of security in the case of undefined behavior that happens to work.

Comment: The key phrase you want to look up to answer this question is ["name hiding"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html).

Comment: -1. Do a basic research first since this is a very basic question, ask the compiler, then perhaps ask a more specific question.

Comment: @Antimony well if you prefer to read the standard then have it your way. All I care is that people do a little research before asking questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual function calling a non-virtual function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796626/virtual-function-calling-a-non-virtual-function)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! It makes sense now!  And sorry for the sloppy syntax; I wrote this kinda on the fly and was just hoping to get the gist of what I wanted across.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The code in question will not compile because `Base::method1()` is declared `private`.
It needs to be `public` to be able to be called from `main`.

---

`Derived::method1()` is implicitly `virtual` even if not marked as `virtual`. So the `this` in `Derived::method1()` points to a `Dervied` object and in this scope compiler can only see `Derived::method2()`. Hence `Derived::method2()` will be called. The method in derived class **hides** the same named method in Base class.

---

**Good Read:**

**[What's the meaning of, Warning: Derived::f(char) hides Base::f(double)?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)**

Answer (score 2):

The main reason you do not see this pattern very often is that it is in fact an anti-pattern.

The Derived method will be invoked because you are calling it with a Derived object reference (this).  If you were calling it with a Base class reference you will get the Base method.

If you redeclare a non-virtual method you are hiding the base method and breaking polymorphism.

Comment: +1 for several good points (especially significance of `this`), but regarding "redeclare a non-virtual method [is] breaking polymorphism" - that's a bit melodramatic: the object may continue to work polymorphically through a Base class reference/pointer perfectly well - as per Liskov Substitution Principle - or it may even be necessary not to have some functions virtual to avoid breaking the principle (e.g. a Derived class serialisation method that wasn't reparsable as per Base method documentation).  Not broken, but fragile (e.g. harder to switch to compile-time polymorphism).

Comment: Good point.  There are almost always exceptions to the rule.  I tend to stick with this particular rule pretty heavily as it reduces the likelihood of error in large code bases.  This is a contradiction to what one would expect.  I guess you could say it inflates polymorphism because now you are making an object that takes many forms based on how you refer to it :P.

Answer (score 1):

It will use `Derive::method2()` as name look-up (in body of `Derive::method1()`) starts from the class itself.