# Virtual function calling a non-virtual function and vice versa

Tags: c++, dynamic-binding, run-time-polymorphism

I have a `class A` as a base class of `class B`.

I have called the *non-virtual* function, `abc()`, within my *virtual* function, `xyz()`, as mentioned below.

Due to run-time polymorphism, `B:xyz` is called – I understand this.

However, I don't understand, why was it followed by `B:abc` and not `A:abc`, as `abc` is a non-virtual function.

Please note: I have come across the following question: [Virtual function calling a non-virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796626/virtual-function-calling-a-non-virtual-function). It mentions that calling `abc()` within the virtual function is equivalent to `this->abc()`, hence the output. However, I am not sure I understand this part.

Because, when I do the opposite (i.e. a non-virtual function calling a virtual function), that time correct run time polymorphism is displayed. What happens to the this pointer then?

```cpp
//Virtual function calling non-virtual 
class A
{
  public:
  void abc()
  {
    cout<<"A:abc"<<endl;
  }

  virtual void xyz()
  {
    cout<<"A:xyz"<<endl;
    abc();
  }
};


class B: public A
{
  public:
  void abc()
  {
    cout<<"B:abc"<<endl;
  }

  void xyz()
  {
    cout<<"B:xyz"<<endl;
    abc();
  }
};

int main() {

  A *obj3 = new B;
  obj3->xyz();\
  return 0;
}
```

```
Output
B:xyz
B:abc
```

```
//Non-virtual calling virtual function
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
  public:

  void abc()
  {
    cout<<"A:abc"<<endl;
    xyz();
  }

  virtual void xyz()
  {
    cout<<"A:xyz"<<endl;
  }
};

class B: public A
{
  public:

  void abc()
  {
    cout<<"B:abc"<<endl;
    xyz();
  }

  void xyz()
  {
    cout<<"B:xyz"<<endl;
  }
};

int main() {

  A *obj3 = new B;
  obj3->abc(); 
  return 0;
}
```

```
Output
A:abc
B:xyz
```

Comment: Please clarify *However I dont understand, why was it followed by B:abc and not A:abc as abc is a non-virtual function* What do you mean my *followed by B:abc*? Far as I can tell `B::abc` is never invoked.

Comment: @user4581301 check the output of first case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calls to your **non-virtual** `abc` function are resolved, effectively, at compile time: so, when that is called from *within* another member function of `class B`, the `class B` version of the function is called, and is passed a pointer (`this`) to the object from which it is being called; similarly, if called from *within* a `class A` function, then the `class A` definition will be used. That is to say, to the compiler, non-virtual functions associate with a class, rather than any particular instance of the class.

However, your **virtual** `xyz` function is handled differently by the compiler; in this case, a reference or pointer to the function is added to the class definition (this is generally added into what is known as a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), although the details are implementation-specific); when any objects of your class(es) are created, they include a copy of that function pointer and/or vtable. When the compiler sees code to call such a virtual function, it translates that into a call *via* the appropriate function pointer; so, the function 'travels with' the *actual* object: whether the function is called from the derived class or base class (in your code) is irrelevant – the function called is the one belonging to the object (instance) from which it is invoked.

In summary: calls to non-virtual functions are resolved at *compile time*, whereas calls to virtual functions are (conceptually) resolved at *run time*.

To see creation of this "vtable" in action, try compiling and running the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int i;
    ~A() = default;
    void foo() { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};

class B {
public:
    int i;
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(A) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(B) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The *only* difference between the two classes is that one has virtual functions and the other doesn't – yet that causes a significant difference in the size of class objects: the size of the vtable (with, possibly, some 'padding' for optimal alingment of data)! (On my 64-bit Windows, using MSVC, I get sizes of 4 and 16, but the actual values will vary between compilers and platforms.)

Comment: So even when a virtual function is called from within a member function, the ‘actual object’ is used and not ‘this’?

Comment: The `this` pointer is still used (it is an 'invisible' parameter to any non-static member function calls); in fact, it is even more important, because that (i.e. this) points to the object that has the vtable.

Comment: Code 2: non virtual function of class A is called i.e. abc(). From within this member function of class A, a virtual function xyz is called. So within the member function of class A, if vptr is used to resolve then wouldn’t this->vptr of class A be used? How did it rightly called derived class function.

Comment: @SumaiyaA Read my answer again: the vtable is taken from ***each object at runtime*** and the `this` pointer in your Code 2 points to a `B` object (because it was created with `new B`). That is polymorphism working: the object (and its pointer) carries its virtual function with it, *wherever* it goes!

Comment: *"whereas calls to virtual functions are (and can only be) resolved at run time"*. Optimizer might *"de-virtualize"* the code, following the as-if rule. From OP code, we "know" that dynamic type of `obj3` is `B`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Fair point - edited to be less assertive about run-time resolution.