# C++ call a non virtual function from virtual function in derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

In fact, similar questions were asked [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309124/how-does-the-base-class-non-virtual-function-get-called-when-derived-class-objec) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796626/virtual-function-calling-a-non-virtual-function), but the answers were not satisfied. The code example is

```
class  CBase
{
public:
    virtual void act1(){cout<<"CBase::act1()! "<<endl;  act2();}
    void act2()        {cout<<"CBase::act2()! "<<endl;  act3();}
    virtual void act3(){cout<<"CBase::act3()! "<<endl;  act4();}
    virtual void act4(){cout<<"CBase::act4()! "<<endl;  act5();}
    void act5()        {cout<<"CBase::act5()! "<<endl;    }
    virtual ~CBase(){}
} ;

class  CDerive : public  CBase
{
public:
    void act3(){cout<<"CDerive::act3()! "<<endl; act4();}
    void act4(){cout<<"CDerive::act4()! "<<endl; act5();}    
    void act5(){cout<<"CDerive::act5()! "<<endl;        }
    virtual ~CDerive(){}
} ;
int main()
{
    CBase *p=new CDerive;
    p->act1();
    cout<<endl;
    p->act5();
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
CBase::act1()! 
CBase::act2()! 
CDerive::act3()! 
CDerive::act4()! 
CDerive::act5()! 

CBase::act5()!
```

With respect to `p->act1()`

- since `act1()` is a virtual function and derived class doesn't implement it, the program will call `CBase::act1()`;
- then program will call `CBase::act2()`;
- `act3()` is a vritual function, the program will call `CDervie::act3()`;
- `act4()` is also a vritual function, the program will call `CDervie::act4()`;
- here comes the part that I don't understand, `act5()` is not a virtual function, and `p` is a pointer belonging to `CBase`, basically `p` can only access the function in `CBase`! But the output is `CDerive::act5()!`

In contrast, `p->act5()` will call `CBase::act5()` as I think.

There seems to be contradictory between the principle - the base class pointer can only access the function defined in base class and virtual function, and the real output. The reason can't be explained from virtual table either, since `CDerive::act5()` is not even in the virtual table. So, my questions are

- what is the rationale behind those ?
- what did happen when `CBase *p=new CDerive` or `CDerive a; CBase *p=&a`?

Comment: You call `act5` from `CDerive::act4`... static type is so `CDerive`.

Comment: Possibly relevant (or even a duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/67065428/10871073

Comment: In the first case, it is not `p` that accesses `act5`, but  the `CDerive` instance itself, inside `CDerive::act4`. When you call a non-virtual member function from another member function, it is selected based on the static type of `*this` in that member function.

Comment: @AdrianMole what a coincidence, we both asked the same kind of question at the same time

Comment: @molbdnilo I think I understand what you mean. Thank you very much, and I will write down my understanding below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to re-state your bullet points, and make small changes to them.

- `act1()` is a non-abstract, public virtual function that exists in `CBase` and **not** `CDerive`, so `p` uses the implementation in `CBase`. Because it was implemented in `CBase`, it is not required to be overridden in a child class
- Same as above for `act2()`. Note that `act2()` is non-virtual
- `act3() is a virtual function in` CBase`, and is overridden in` CDerive`. Since` p`is allocated as a`CDerive`, the override is used and` act3()`is called from`CDerive`
- Same as above for `act4()`
- Because `act4()` above was called from a `CDerive` object, the call to `act5()` will also come from `CDerive`

New bullet:

- Then in main, this line `p->act5()` calls the `CBase` version. This is because `p` is a `CBase*`, and `act5()` is not virtual. So it follows that it calls from `CBase`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point of this question is the understanding of `this` pointer. When compiling, the real function is (taking `CDerive::act4()` as an example)

```
void CDerive::act4(CDerive *this)
{
    cout<<"CDerive::act4()! "<<endl; 
    this->act5();
}
```

So, `this->act5()` is equivalent to `CDerive::act5()` and the output is `CDerive::act5()!`.

But wait, this seems to be contradictory to the function `CBase::act2()`. Following the same logic, the real function should be

```
void CBase::act2(CBase *this)        
{
    cout<<"CBase::act2()! "<<endl;  
    this->act3();
}
```

and `this->act3()` will call `CBase::act3()`, this is not right!

So, the real calling procedure is

```
if func() is not a virtual function 
    this -> func() = class::func() 
else
    this -> func() = v_ptr -> v_talbe -> func()
```

using two examples above to demonstrate it :

- `act5()` is not a virtual function, so the program will call `CDerive::act5()`
- `act3()` is a virtual funciton, so the program will call `CDerive::act3()`

In this way, the logic is consistent and the output is right.